# How to get Count of Number of Past Connected Displays

Tags: macos, display, system-settings

I'm on a MacBook Pro, MacOS version Sonoma 14.2. I've noticed that each time I connect to a new external display, my Mac is able to remember my configuration for it (and for any combinations of multiple displays as well), as when I reconnect I don't need to reconfigure.

This means that somewhere in the system, the MAC address of the external display is stored along with the associated configuration. I've gotten curious *how many external displays I've connected to since I got my laptop*.

Where in the system can I find the answer to that question? Is there somewhere in the system logs I can find that list of MAC addresses to count and see?